# Calculate Hours depending on workdays, month, hours per day

Tags: excel

I made a formula in excel, yet when trying it out, it responds with `NAME?`

`=IF(MAAND(VANDAAG()) > MAAND(D1); (NETTO.WERKDAGEN(D1; D3)) * D5; D6)`

[image]

My goal is to calculate how many Hours I still need **This Month** in Row 8.
depending on startdate(startdatum and **current date (huidige datum)** (not enddate(einddatum)) and how many work days there are between those dates times the hours.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

**UPDATE**
translations:

- Maand = Month
- Vandaag = Today
- Netto.WerkDagen = NETWORKDAYS

Comment: separate each bit and test to find what is not working. I would try but cannot work out the function translations.

Comment: @SolarMike right.. let me translate that

Comment: #NAME means excel does not recognize a function, so test each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I had to use ALS (dutch translation).....